# Process monitoring with email alerts

Tags: debian, monitoring, process

What are the tools available in debian (highly preferable from standard repositories) that would allow me to monitor one or several processes on my server and send an alert email when processes have stopped/crashed optionally executing some other configurable actions such as running shell script?

I am aware that Zabbix has similar functionality, but setting up and tuning Zabbix for such simple use seems to be an overkill.

`EDIT:` Would be great if it actually had similar way of pointing to the process as it is done in Zabbix, e.g. by checking if the certain port is busy/in_use etc.

Comment: Supervise can to respawn services. Not sure about alerts.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `monit` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I put a small addition to the question. Check it out. Does `monit` have same way to point which process to watch? Also is it `monit` package that i can see in repository cache?

Comment: Yes, it does. Read more at http://mmonit.com/monit/ and http://packages.debian.org/fr/wheezy/monit